# IBM App ID: Which URL to use to allow sign up and reset?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

From documentation I can see the folowing about "Forgot Password"

Pass WebAppStrategy "show" property and set it to WebAppStrategy.FORGOT_PASSWORD, will launch the App ID forgot password from.

app.get("/forgot_password", passport.authenticate(WebAppStrategy.STRATEGY_NAME, {
    successRedirect: LANDING_PAGE_URL,
    show: WebAppStrategy.FORGOT_PASSWORD
}));

Note:

```
This process will end without retrieving App ID access and id tokens.
Make sure to set "Allow users to sign up and reset their password" and "Forgot password email" to ON, in Cloud Directory settings that are in the App ID dashboard.
```

My question is where (which url?) do you use to allow sign up and reset ?

Kind regards

Comment: The note refers to the fact that you need to enable the reset password flow from your App ID console. If you are the instance owner, go to https://console.bluemix.net, login, and select the App ID instance. Then go to ‘Cloud dorectory’ under ‘Identity providers’, youll find the relevant settings there.

Comment: "Forgot password email" exists as a setting on the tab "Reset password". I cannot find "Allow users to sign up and reset their password" anywhere. This could refer to "Allow users to sign-up and manage their account from your app" on the "Settings" tab and probably got renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to [switch sign up and reset on is part of the App ID Cloud Directory](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/cloud-directory.html#cd). The App ID service basically has two ways of providing an identity to applications. One is as wrapper around other identity providers (social logins, SAML enterprise directories), the other is by having a Cloud Directory as its own user database.

If the Cloud Directory is turned on, then administrators can add and manage users and they can configure whether users can "self-manage" sign up, password reset and other things.

Once you have provisioned IBM App ID, go to the service dashboard, locate the Cloud Directory and configure it.